# ActionBarSherlock and Spinner Dialog theming

Tags: android, spinner, actionbarsherlock

I have an application where I use customized (styled) Spinners with Dialog style dropdowns. I inherited my application theme from Theme.Sherlock. I test on Jelly Bean or ICS devices for now. If I use the spinners in a normal activity, the spinner dropdowns are OK: they have a Holo dark grey background and holo blue text color. But if I use the spinners in a SherlockFragmentActivity, the dropdowns are styled the old way: they have black titlebar and white background.

The problem is that this does not look consistent in my app and that my spinner dropdowns have white text color.

What I figured out so far:

My app's theme is inherited from android:Theme.Holo at the end, but it is probably overridden by the SherlockFragmentActivity's theme. But I couldn't find out where this is styled and how can I override the background of the spinners.

So how this is done?